# A game of psychology and/or math.

Tags: probability, game-theory, gambling, algorithmic-game-theory

Consider the following game.

> You and your opponent is given a uniform random number in the interval $(0,1)$.
>   Player 1 looks at his number and can either bet or fold. If he folds, he loses nothing and the round is over. If he bets and his opponent folds, he wins 1 dollar and the opponent loses nothing. If he bets and his opponent calls, the one with the highest number wins 2 dollars and the loser loses 1 dollar.

So this is an asymmetric game, where player 1 can bet or fold and player 2 can call(if given the chance) or fold. Both players looks at their number before action is taken.

Is this a game of psychology or is there a mathematical way to solve this game? How?

There is only 1 round in this game.

This game is like poker, I was wondering how to assess this situation mathematically? And in isolation.

Comment: Barring communication between the players, it's a game of maths and has nothing to do with psychology as they have no information on each other.

Comment: @Shuri2060  Not sure I agree.  Player $1$ can bluff.   if $1$ draws $0$ but bets anyway, he can hope to trick $2$ into folding a winning hand.

Comment: "If he bets and his opponent folds, he wins 1 dollar and the opponent loses nothing."  Does this mean that they both win nothing? Back where they started?  " If he bets and his opponent calls, the one with the highest number wins 2 dollars and the loser loses 1 dollar." Are you creating money out of thin air?

Comment: Assuming that you actually mean that money should be preserved, this game devolves into no one ever betting.  Any strategy to bet on less than a 1 (such as betting on $1 - \epsilon$) would be beaten by a strategy only betting on $(1 - \epsilon / 2)$.  There is a reason they require antes in poker, or on one would ever bet unless they got a royal flush.

Comment: Look it means exactly what i wrote. Money is created yes.

Comment: When money is created it starts to be a psychology question instead of a math question.  The players could collude to increase each other's money since it is no longer strictly adversarial.

Comment: I see but there is only 1 round. These players can not meet eachother again ever and split the money. ;)

Comment: As @DanielV writes, I think this game is defined in a strange way (creating money out of thin air). The game sounds very much like a simpler version of the game described in this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917807/game-theory-optimal-solution-to-2-player-betting-game
Have look and see if this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player $1$s strategy is a function $p(x)$ which is the probability he bets given that his number is $x$.  Similarly player $2$ has a strategy $q(y)$ which is the probability he calls if he can given that his number is $y$.  Each player seeks to find a strategy which will maximize his outcome.  Each has a floor of zero which is achieved by always folding.  The analysis seems difficult particularly because of the continuous range of strategies for each player.  I think I would start by doing the analysis for a game where each player gets one of a discrete set of numbers, starting with two, then three, and so on.  I would hope to find a pattern in the probability distributions that I could extend to the continuous case.  A challenge is that you need to have a rule about what happens with ties in the discrete case, but that should lose impact as the number of possible values increases and the chance of a tie decreases.

Added:  Using a deterministic strategy where player $1$ bets when his number is above $x_0$ and player $2$ calls when his number is above $y_0$ with cutoffs forced to be a multiple of $0.05$ I find player $1$ should bet with a cutoff of $0.25$ and gets a minimum value of $0.375$ when player $2$ calls with a cutoff of $0.5$.  With those values player $2$ gets $0.375$ as well.  The figure below shows the region with player $1$s number on the horizontal axis and player $2$s number on the vertical axis.  The numbers in the square are the payoff to player $1$ in each region.  There is a change in the calculation when $y_0 \lt x_0$ because the trapezoid region changes over.  I just computed the average player $1$ payoff for each combination of $(x_0,y_0)$.  For each $x_0$ I took the minimum over all $y_0$s, so that is the minimum player $2$ can let player $1$ have by choosing $y_0$.  I then took the maximum over $x_0$ to get the result.  I did not prove that this maximizes player $2$s expectation.[image]

Comment: Is ther eany reason the strategy shouldnt be deterministic? Can you prove thats an advantage? I actually computed some for the discrete case, I computed the optimal strategy based on the strategy for the opponent, then i computed the other guys strategy based on this new strategy etc, what I found is no convergence of strategy but oscillating regularly, how to interpret this?

Comment: You could certainly have a $p(x)$ that is $0$ for $x$ less than some threshold and $1$ above that.  I suspect that is not optimal, but it might be.  If you require both players to play deterministically the analysis for each to find the threshold should not be hard.

Comment: Can you explain abit how you computed this? What if player 2 knows player 1 s cutoff, can he achieve better by changing his own?

Comment: This seems to be a Nash equilibrium, I verified your result, why was their expectation values equal is this a coincidence?

Comment: I don't see any particular reason for  the payoffs to be the same.  In my diagram the payoff to player $2$ is $0$ where the payoff to player $1$ is $1$ and the $2$ and $-1$ are swapped.

Comment: Have a look at this very similar question and my partial answer for it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917807/game-theory-optimal-solution-to-2-player-betting-game  I would love your input there too :)

Comment: If player 1 bets, neither of player 2's strategies dominates the other. Player 1 has an incentive to bluff, viz the hope that player 2 will fold so player 1 wins \$1. I propose the following model: Player 1's strategy has 2 parameters $f, b$; they fold if $f<x<b$ and bet otherwise. Player 2 can#t influence player 1, so they can't profit from bluffing, so their strategy has 1 parameter $c$. They call if $y>c$ and fold otherwise.